# Find region and limit for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n+1)z^n$ in complex variable

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

**Problem** Find the region for which the series converges and find the limit ($z \in \mathbb{C}$).

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(n+1)z^n$$

**Atempt** By using the ratio test we have in both we have $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left|\frac{(n+1)(n+2)z^{n+1}}{n(n+1)z^n}\right|=|z|$$ then that serie converges absolutely for $|z| < 1$. But I have problems to find the limit, could you help me please?

Comment: Hint: Write first series as $-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}(-z^3)^n$. As for the second, if $F(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$, then $ F'(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty nz^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)z^n$. Do you see how to finish?

Answer (score 1):

It's$$z\left(\sum_{n\ge1}z^{n+1}\right)^{\prime\prime}=z\left(\tfrac{z^2}{1-z}\right)^{\prime\prime}=z\left(\tfrac{1}{1-z}-1-z\right)^{\prime\prime}.$$You can do the rest.